# How do I update the serial monitor without printing a new line each time?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I'm testing out an accelerometer and I want to know if there's a way to make it so that the serial monitor will update the values without printing a new line. Ideally the serial monitor would say something like:

```
Accelerometer X: $xval
Accelerometer y: $yval
```

and then instead of printing two new lines each time, it just updates the values. Is there anyway to do that in Arduino? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you make the serial monitor 20 lines long. And then print your 2 lines + 18 lines? I'm not sure, but it might fake a 'value update'

Answer (score 6):

The ultra-basic "serial monitor" in the Arduino IDE cannot do what you want.

Instead you need to either write a special client program, or use a more standard serial terminal program, such as Tera Term (Windows), Minicom (Linux), etc.

These standard serial terminal programs use a special sequence of characters called *ANSI escape codes* which manipulate the display, doing such things as setting colours, moving the cursor around, etc.

More information on ANSI escape codes can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 3):

No. The serial monitor does not support terminal handling. Either use a serial communications program that does and use those features, or write a custom client that will only update those values in its interface.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there any other client that's recommended?

Comment: Not really. Most serial programs, even Hyperterminal (or whatever Windows drags along these days) will do.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [processing](https://processing.org/). You can use that to view the accelerometers position in 3d and see the values changing if that's what you want. The official Arduino site talks about it [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/processing).  Here is a great [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing) on it.

Comment: I would recommend this as a client option.

Comment: Probably would have been better as a comment on Ignacio
But yes processing is a good option IF you want to write code by yourself.